# Angular js how to highlight first point on line graph/chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, charts, highcharts

A name filter (text box) should also be present which will filter the cities based on the input value and should get displayed on graph, not able to find way out.

```
var temp = [{"name":"bangalore","temprature":25},{"name":"chennai","temprature":45},{"name":"mumbai","temprature":40},{"name":"goa","temprature":35},{"name":"madurai","temprature":38}];

var label= [];
var value= [];
var value1 = [];

var array =  eval( temp );
for( var i = 0; i < array.length; i++ ) {
        label.push(array[i].name);
        value.push(array[i].temprature);
}

value1.push(value);

var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['chart.js']);
myApp.controller('myController',function($http,$scope){ 

      $scope.labels = label;
      $scope.data = value1;
      $scope.idSelectedVote = 1;
```

I have requirement of highlighting first Node in plotted graph, but not able to find wayout in Angular js chart.

Comment: Your question is not clear. I'd suggest adding your view code to help. A couple notes: Your initialization belongs in the controller section, instead of creating global variables like you are. The eval(temp) is redundant and can be removed. The looping through your data and creating new arrays is probably not necessary; you can probably do this by changing the ng-repeat in your view.

Comment: If you have a problem with Highcharts please recreate the problem in JSFiddle using exemplary data and specify what are you trying to achieve, so we could suggest a fitting solution.